# binding elements of array with a specified order

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have an array of dim=c(2,2,64), which I would like to turn into a matrix of dim=c(16,16).The order by which I need to fill the matrix is by the array's 3d dimension by rows and columns, without changing the order of elements of  the rows or columns.

```
 data1<-matrix(seq(1:4),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
 data1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4

data2<-matrix(c(5,6,7,8),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
data2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    6
[2,]    7    8

data3<-matrix(c(9,10,11,12),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
data3
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   10
[2,]   11   12
```

and I would like to get something like this, with the next element of the array (data3) being in the 1st column and 3 row of the new matrix etc.

```
data.comp
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    5    6
[2,]    3    4    7    8
```

I have tried combinations of the aperm with abind command but couldn't figure it out.
Is there a way without using a loop?

Comment: can you dput you array of dim=c(2,2,64) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, is the following:

You practically have something like this:

```
#I am following your example but I am using 4 2x2 matrices
#in order to make it work
ar <- array(NA, c(2,2,4))
#too lazy to write a loop...
ar[,,1] <- data1
ar[,,2] <- data2
ar[,,3] <- data3
ar[,,4] <- data4
```

And one way to do it is this:

```
#initiate two vectors which will host
#columns 1:2 and 3:4
temp_mat1 <- c()
temp_mat2 <- c()
for(i in 1:dim(ar)[3]){
  if(i%%2==0) {
    #if i is even create columns 3:4
    temp_mat1 <- rbind(temp_mat1, ar[,,i])
    }else{
    #if i is odd create columns 1:2
    temp_mat2 <- rbind(temp_mat2, ar[,,i])
    }  
}

#then column bind them together
cbind(temp_mat2, temp_mat1)
```

Output:

```
> cbind(temp_mat2, temp_mat1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    5    6
[2,]    3    4    7    8
[3,]    9   10   13   14
[4,]   11   12   15   16
```